# Extract stats from datetime intervals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL database with some table stored as innoDB type. One of them is `work_session` and its structure is:

- `id` int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary
- `project_id` int(10) unsigned index
- `begin` datetime
- `end` datetime

The table is used to register the time spent for each project. Of course in each row `end` is bigger than `begin`. Multiple rows may have the same `project_id` but intervals denoted by `begin` and `end` of rows with the same `project_id` don't overlap.

My aim is to extract some stats from this table. In particular:

- Time spent for each `project_id`
- Time spent in each day for each `project_id`, from the first recorded activity to now
- Time spent by hour of the day for each `project_id`
- Time spent by day of the week for each `project_id`

I was able to achieve this using PHP but I want to learn how to do it with MySQL.

I was able to obtain the first stat with

```
SELECT 
  `project_id`,
  SUM(`work_session_duration`) AS `project_duration`
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `project_id`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `begin`, `end`) AS `work_session_duration`
   FROM `work_sessions`) AS `t1`
GROUP BY `project_id`
```

The other three stats are very similar, in particular the last two, but I'm not able to figure out a way to them with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hourly statistic is the most difficult part. So i will only provide a solution for it. Other questions can be solved in a similar way.

You will need some helper tables:

`calendar`

```
|    date    |
|------------|
| 1970-01-01 |
| 1970-01-02 |
| ...        |
| 1940-12-30 |
| 1940-12-31 |
```

`hours`

```
| hour |
|------|
|    0 |
|    1 |
|  ... |
|   22 |
|   23 |
```

You can find many answers on SO, how to create such tables. I will skip that part to keep my answer compact.

With the helper tables you can create a CROSS JOIN in a subquery containing any date-hour combination you need for your data. That subquery can be joined with your table on overlapping. Then you can group by `project_id` and  `h.hour` and calculate the sum of worked time:

```
select s.project_id, h.hour,
    sum(timestampdiff(second, greatest(s.begin, h.begin), least(s.end, h.end))) as project_duration
from (    
    select h.hour,
           timestamp(c.date, concat(h.hour, ':00:00')) as `begin`,
           timestamp(c.date, concat(h.hour+1, ':00:00')) as `end`
    from calendar c
    cross join hours h
    where c.date >= (select date(min(`begin`)) from work_sessions)
      and c.date <= (select date(max(`end`))   from work_sessions)
) h
inner join work_sessions s
    on  s.begin < h.end
    and s.end   > h.begin
group by s.project_id, h.hour
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I deleted from your query the `date` from the `where` condition because `begin` and `end` are already date format. Anyway your query is better than my tries so I'll try to work on it.

Comment: @qiusva Your fix on `least` and `greatest` is correct. The changes on `hours.begin` and `hours.end` do also make sense. But the `WHERE` condition in the subquery is there for performance reasons. It will limit the subquery result to the range that exists in the `work_sessions` table. I changed it a bit, so it should work now. You might also want to change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, if you want to show hours, which nobody has worked on.

Comment: I have to be sincere, I understood that it is for performance but, besides that there is an error using `date`, the results of the query are incorrect with the `where` condition. Also, if there is only one row in the table `min` and `max` return nothing. I don't know why.

Comment: @giusva Hmm.. I think it works as expected in this demo: http://rextester.com/IJWAT4324 - What is the data type of `begin` and `end`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
SELECT 
  `project_id`,
  SUM(`work_session_duration`) AS `project_duration`,
  `days`
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `project_id`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `begin`, `end`) AS `work_session_duration`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`begin`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `days`
   FROM `work_sessions`) AS `t1`
GROUP BY `project_id`, `days`
ORDER BY `days`
```

and

```
SELECT 
  `project_id`,
  SUM(`work_session_duration`) AS `project_duration`,
  HOUR(`begin`) AS `hours`
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `project_id`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `begin`, `end`) AS `work_session_duration`,
    `begin`
   FROM `work_sessions`) AS `t1`
GROUP BY `project_id`, `hours`
```

and

```
SELECT 
  `project_id`,
  SUM(`work_session_duration`) AS `project_duration`,
  WEEKDAY(`begin`) AS `weekdays`
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `project_id`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `begin`, `end`) AS `work_session_duration`,
    `begin`
   FROM `work_sessions`) AS `t1`
GROUP BY `project_id`, `weekdays`
```

Or something like this...

Comment: All the three have the same erroneous behavior if a work session starts in a day and end in another one (first and second stats) or if a work session starts in an hour and ends in another one (third stats). I think that, if there isn't any function that can help, there is the needing of using control flow functions like `IF`, `ELSE`, `CASE`, etc...